# How to change backcolor of an open ToolStripDropDownButton?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I need to change back-color of a `ToolStripDropDownButton` when its drop-down is opened. How can I do it?

I tried to inherit a class from the `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` and then override the `OnRenderDropDownButtonBackground`, but it only affects when the drop-down is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use the following approaches:

**1-st approach:**

```
toolStripDropDownButton1.Paint += toolStripDropDownButton1_Paint;
//...
void toolStripDropDownButton1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    if(toolStripDropDownButton1.Pressed) {
        // TODO Paint your pressed button
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
}
```

**2-nd approach:**

```
toolStrip.Renderer = new PressedRenderer();
//...    

class PressedRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
    protected override void OnRenderDropDownButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
        if(e.Item.Pressed)
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Green);
        else base.OnRenderDropDownButtonBackground(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course yes! We can paint anything via the 1st way. I use a color pallet in my app to determine the tool-strip items color, so I'm looking for a simple way to set some desired color as back-color of any arbitrary drop-down button. I tried the 2nd way, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on background!

Comment: +1 I'll mark your 1st approach as the answer if I cannot find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [`OnDropDownOpened`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.ondropdownopened.aspx) event what you want?

```
private void toolStripDropDownButton_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   toolStripDropDownButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```